# Reactjs compile's assets by path static/

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, compiler-warnings, npx

I am very new to reactjs learning from YouTube channel.

I am using ubuntu, using npx create-react-app on compile in terminal observing different way of compile compared to other compiles in reactjs.

My project details:

```
{
  "name": "reactwrk",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
```

NPM and NPX version => 8.3.0

Nodejs version => 16.13.1

Kindly please explain why it was happening like this.

[image: Please check this image for your reference]

Answer (score 0):

That's because of `react-scripts@5.0.0`, which was released a couple weeks ago. It ships with webpack@5 and different configurations.

If you want, you can downgrade to the previous version, 4.0.3. I recommend doing that anyway because 5.0.0 has some serious bugs and they're likely not getting fixed before the holidays are over.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you please guide how i can downgrade to webpack 4.0.3

Comment: `yarn add react-scripts@4.0.3`

Comment: Summer one more thing, can we install react old version other than this 17.0.2?

like 17.0.0 or 17.0.1 Version of react...

Comment: Yes, of course. But I think react-scripts@4.0.3 only supports react 16.8.x and above.

Answer (score 0):

cause of webpack,

if you don't want to see this, you can edit
`node_modules/webpack/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js`

comment line: `new DefaultStatsPrinterPlugin().apply(compiler);`